# Can't C++ POD type have any constructor?

Tags: c++

I have a class and a const variable.

```
struct A 
{
    int b;
};

A const a;
```

The class `A` is POD and can be initialized like this.

```
A const a = { 3 };
```

IMHO, it looks fine to have a constructor like this.

```
struct A 
{
    int b;

    A(int newB) : b(newB)
    {
    }
};
```

But Clang assumes `A` as non-aggregate type. Why I can't have constructor like that? Or should I do something else?

---

I modified question to present my original meaning. I had wrote the `struct` as `class` by mistake, and sorry for @Johannes about confusing :)

Comment: Eonil: I believe, my answer clarifies your all doubts, especially the quotation from the Standard.

Comment: You need to decide what you question is about: 1) POD-types or 2) simply the ability to use the `{}` initializer (i.e. aggregates). At this time it is not clear what specifically is the problem.

Comment: @Nawaz Thanks for care. Your answer is what I want!

Comment: @AndreyT My question was about constructor on POD type. I had wanted to use constructor syntax instead of `{...}` syntax. But now I know my idea was wrong.

Comment: @AndreT: Is it not both same? As in my opinion, in C++03, only aggregate (that means, all variants of it) can be initialized with `{}`? And aggregate-class is nothing but POD-class, right?

Comment: @Nawaz: No, that's not even remotely correct. For a simple example, an array of `std::string` objects is an aggregate, but not a POD. And you can initialize such array with `{}` initializer even though it is not a POD.

Comment: @Eonil: The ability to use the `{}` initializer syntax depends on whether the object is an *aggregate* or not. Being an *aggregate* has very little to do with being a *POD* type. If what you care about is the `{}` initializer, then you can forget about POD - it has nothing to do with it whatsoever.

Comment: @AndreyT I was just confused about whether POD type can have user-defined ctor or not. Because documents about POD does not mention about ctor, and the mention was in aggregation type section :) And I have to care about POD because its the only type can be passed to C functions like GL...

Comment: @AndreyT: I think, it's implicitly clear from OP's sample code that he wants POD-struct/class, not an array!

Comment: @Nawaz: There's absolutely no difference whether it is an array or not. All aggregates are the same in this respect. Another example would be a struct with `std::string` members and no other members. Is it a POD? No. Is is an aggregate? Yes. So, how is your "the same" doing in this case?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`POD` means Plain Old Data type which by definition cannot have user-defined constructor.

POD is actually an aggregate type (see the next quotation). So what is aggregate? The C++ Standard says in section §8.5.1/1,

> An aggregate is an array or a class
>   (clause 9) with **no user-declared
>   constructors** (12.1), no private or
>   protected nonstatic data members
>   (clause 11), no base classes (clause
>   10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

And section §9/4 from the C++ Standard says,

> [....] A POD-struct is **an aggregate class** that has no non-static data
>   members of type non-POD-struct,
>   non-POD-union (or array of such types)
>   or reference, and has **no user-defined
>   copy assignment operator** and **no
>   user-defined destructor**. Similarly, a
>   POD-union is an aggregate union that
>   has no non-static data members of type
>   non-POD-struct, non-POD-union (or
>   array of such types) or reference, and
>   has **no user-defined copy assignment
>   operator** and **no user-defined
>   destructor**. A POD class is a class
>   that is either a POD-struct or a
>   POD-union.

From this, its also clear that POD class/struct/union though cannot have *user-defined assignment operator* and **user-defined destructor** also.

---

There are however other types of POD. The section §3.9/10 says,

> Arithmetic types (3.9.1),
>   enumeration types, pointer types, and
>   pointer to member types (3.9.2), and
>   cv-qualified versions of these types
>   (3.9.3) are collectively called scalar
>   types. Scalar types, POD-struct types,
>   POD-union types (clause 9), arrays of
>   such types and cv-qualified versions
>   of these types (3.9.3) **are
>   collectively called POD types**.

Read this FAQ : [What is a "POD type"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/intrinsic-types.html#faq-26.7)

Answer (score 6):

> The class A is POD and can be initialized like this

Sorry, that is wrong. Because `b` is private, the class is not a POD.

> But Clang assumes A as non-aggregate type. Why I can't have constructor like that? Or should I do something else?

This is a limitation of C++ as it exists currently. C++0x will not have this limitation anymore. While in C++0x your type is not a POD either, your initialization will work (assuming that you make that constructor `public`).

(Also, I think a better term for you to use here is "aggregate". The requirement for using `{ ... }` is that your class is an aggregate. It doesn't have to be a POD).

Comment: Oh thanks. It was my mistake using `class` instead of `struct`. I'm sorry. I couldn't care about default access. I updated my question. And comment for aggregate but non-POD types is helpful itself :)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers describe the POD rules pretty well. If you want to get a similar initialization style to a constructor for a POD you can use a `make_`-style function, for example:

```
struct A
{
    int i_;
};

A make_A(int i = 0) 
{
    A a = { i }; 
    return a; 
}
```

now you can get initialized POD instances like:

```
A a = make_A();
```