# MSVC const enum type

Tags: c++

```
const enum Alpha{
    X=9,
    Y=5,
    Z=2
}p;
int main(){
    enum Alpha a,b;
    a= X;
    b= Z;

    p = X;
    p = Y;

    printf("%d",a+b-p); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Why is p = X and p = Y allowed in MSVC compiler? This code outputs 6. Shouldn't a const value be assigned at initialization and never again?

Comment: will assigning a to p works ?

Comment: yes, and the output is 2 in that case

Comment: Please indicate your exact compiler version.

Comment: VS2010 compiler with SP1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a bug in the compiler itself. End of the story.

In fact, your little code shows two bugs in the compiler. The first bug is here itself:

```
const enum Alpha{
    X=9,
    Y=5,
    Z=2
}p;    //declaration of p is ill-formed!
```

The declaration of `p` is ill-formed, and thus the compiler should reject this code, because `p` is declared `const` but left *uninitialized*. A `const` scalar (and pod) type  must be initialized in order to be well-formed:

```
const Alpha q;      //ill-formed (same case is with p in your code)
const Alpha r = X;  //well-formed
```

For detailed and extensive explanation, see this:

- [Why do const variables have to be initialized right away?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440381/why-do-const-variables-have-to-be-initialized-right-away)

Comment: Damn, I caught a bug :( Thank you

Comment: Is `Alpha` non-POD? Really?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That *was* typo.

Comment: This still works fine on **VS2013**. Are you guys _sure_ it is a bug?

Comment: Update: **has been fixed in VS2013, it was a bug**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug, indeed.

First of all, global `const` objects must be initialized when defined, and *default-initialization* is not an option for enumeration types. According to Paragraph 8.5/6 of the C++11 Standard:

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the
>   initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>
> — if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
>
> — otherwise, no initialization is performed.
>
> **If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type T, T shall be a class type with a user-provided default constructor**.

Secondly, a `const` object cannot be assigned after initialization.

Answer (score -2):

Edited to match consensus that this is a compiler bug.

This works because the compiler erroneously thinks that p is of type `Alpha` and not `const Alpha`. If you rewrite this as

```
enum Alpha{....
} const p;
```

the compiler will correctly complain that a constant is not being initialized.

```
error C2734: 'p' : const object must be initialized if not extern
error C3892: 'p' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const
```

If you assign the constant,

```
enum Alpha{....
} const p = Y;
```

and remove the assignment to p, everything compiles and works as expected.

Comment: *"This works because p is of type `Alpha` and not `const Alpha`"*. THIS IS WRONG. Type of `p` is `const Alpha`, as `const` applies on the variable, not on the enum definition. Also, `const Alpha p` and `Alpha const p` are the exactly same thing!

Comment: I'm not a language lawyer. I'll leave that to the experts.

Comment: You don't need to be "language lawyer" or "expert" to know that. A good understanding of C++ declaration is more than enough.

Comment: There is still the bit about the PODness and the default constructor. I can't check whether this should compile, but MSVC does, `enum Alpha {...} const p = Alpha();` and it was not immediately clear (at least to me) that this is different from `enum Alpha{...} p;`

Comment: `enum Alpha {...} const p = Alpha();` is absolutely fine, because you're initializing `p`. And the second example `enum Alpha {...} p;`  is also fine, because `p` is not `const` in this case, so you can leave it uninitialized.

Comment: sorry, forgot a const. meant to write: is different from `enum Alpha{...} const p;`,

Comment: That is ill-formed, as `p` is `const` but left uninitialized. :-)

Comment: Yet something like `const struct D{ int a; } d;` compiles and not ill-formed because it is nonPOD and default initialized. That is what I was refering to.

Comment: That too is ill-formed. Which version of which compiler are you using?

Comment: That is MSVC  `11.0.51106.01 Update 1`. But it compiles on the `10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel` as well.

Comment: That must be a bug in MSVC. [GCC is right](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4e60a5b5547c8a93692ea673f3bd5b11) in saying that the code is ill-formed.