# Why would an enum declaration be marked const?

Tags: c++, enums, constants

I saw this construct in the project I work:

```
const enum SomeEnum
{
    val0,
    val1,
    val2
};
```

What is the purpose of `const` here?

Comment: I believe this is invalid C++ code but Visual Studio does accept it (GCC doesn't). In addition Visual Studio also accepts `const class A { /* ... */ };`.

Comment: Related MSVC bug: [MSVC const enum type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14923403)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nothing at all. Actually, according to G++ it is a compiler error:

```
error: qualifiers can only be specified for objects and functions
```

However, in C it is allowed, but useless. GCC says:

```
warning: useless type qualifier in empty declaration
```

The issue is that `const` only applies to objects (variables) and member functions, but not to  basic types.

Answer (score 15):

It doesn't make a difference in your code, but it would in this case:

```
const enum SomeEnum
{
    val0,
    val1,
    val2
} VAL0 = val0;
```

Here, `VAL0` would be a `const` variable (with the value `val0`). TBH though, it isn't of much use.

Comment: I think it *does* make difference: "it shouldn't compile".

Comment: @Nawaz I saw that it didn't compile, however that might just be the compiler. Is there anything in the rules against it? I've seen compilers both accepting and rejecting `static struct X{};`.

Comment: Same thing as doing `const int;` or similar I would imagine.

Comment: In C++, expressions can be `const` or `volatile`, not the types. It is like writing `const int;` as @chris said.

Comment: @Nawaz I agree it doesn't make sense, what I'm saying is I don't think this is addressed directly (that I know of), so it might be up to the compiler.

Comment: in vc++ 2012 i am able to do ++VAL0; I don't understand how his const is undergoing to ++. Can anyone help me to understand ?