# Issue with switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement

Let's see the problem by code:

**code-1**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a =1;
    switch (a)
    {
        printf("This will never print\n");
    case 1: 
        printf(" 1");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Here the `printf()` statement is never going to execute - see http://codepad.org/PA1quYX3. But

**code-2**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 1;
    switch (a)
    {
        int b;
    case 1:
        b = 34; 
        printf("%d", b);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Here `int b` is going to be declared - see http://codepad.org/4E9Zuz1e.

I am not getting why in code1 `printf()` doesn't execute but in code2 `int b` is going to execute.

Why?

**Edit:** 
**i got that int b; is declaration and it is allocate memory at compile time so whether control flow reach there or not that declaration will be done.**

Now see this code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   if(1)
   {
    int a; 
   }

a =1;
return 0;
}
```

here int a is in control flow path still yet this not going to compile...why?

Comment: **[My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8535765/1090079)** to [How can a variable be used when its definition is bypassed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8535731/1090079) should explain what is happening

Comment: Note that if the declaration of `b` was `int b = 31`, there'd be no guarantee that the initialization would occur.  The main difference between the `printf()` and the declaration is that the `printf()` statement is executable and the declaration is not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think of `switch` as just a `goto` with labels. It doesn't matter where you `goto`, as long as a variable declaration is above where you use it, you can use it. This is partially due to the fact that a variable declaration is *not* an executable statement that gets "done" like an expression. That switch is very nearly equivalent to:

```
int a  = 1;

{
    if (a == 1) goto case1;
    goto defaultcase;

    int b;

case1:
    b = 34;
    printf("%d", b);
    goto end;

defaultcase:
    goto end;

end:
}

return 0;
```

And the `goto`s have nothing to do with the scope of `b`.

Try doing this though:

```
switch (a)
{
int b = 1;
....
```

In that case, even though `b` is declared, the initialisation will be skipped because that *is* an executable statement that can either be done or not done. Your compiler should warn you if you try to do that.

**Regarding the declaration inside `if` (updated question):**  In that case, `a` has a scope limited to the `if`. It is created when the scope is entered, and is destroyed when the scope ends.

Comment: @Mr.32 in that case, `a` as a scope limited to the `if`. It is created when the scope is entered, and is destroyed when the scope ends. Note that `switch`es do not create a new scope, exactly like labels and `goto`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Shouldn't this (scope/if) be added to the answer in order to reflect the changes of the question?

Comment: @undur If you think it should then I will add it tomorrow, or you can if you have time and energy. Anyone is welcome and should feel free to edit my answers.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Copying the "switches do not create new scope" part  I think it is wrong. 6.8.4: "A selection statement is a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of its enclosing block." applies to both `if` and `switch`.

Comment: @undur_gongor yes I'm sorry, the example was flawed and is now correct, I meant to indicate that each `case` didn't have a new scope.

Answer (score 2):

Because `int b;` is a declaration and the compiler will not generate code for it.

```
int a = 1;

switch (a) {

/* Instructions corresponding to the code here will not be executed */
/* printf("hi"); Instructions for such code will never be executed */
/* int b;      It is just a declaration. No executable code is generated for it*/

int b = 34;/*Replaced int b by int b = 34 now b will never be initialized to 34*/
case 1:
   printf("%d",b);      /*you will get garbage value now*/
   break;
default:
   break;
}
```