# return an immutable POD class from a function

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, immutability

### Context

I'm working on a large project combined from different modules. We've got a `exporter` with a template function `export<T>(const T& obj)` which works **only** on POD types (it does `static_assert` for `is_pod` if you're curious). Currently I'm sitting on the part of the system that's responsible for cataloging some entities (their type is irrelevant) that are described by **metadata**. The metadata itself is returned by some function called `metadata describe(const entity& obj)`, and should be **immutable** after returning. Of course the function itself sets the `metadata` members inside its body.

### Problem

Due to the facts mentioned above, I need to design a **const POD type**. Since POD types [cannot have user-defined constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442717/cant-c-pod-type-have-any-constructor), the member variables themselves cannot be `const`. Also returning a `const` variable by value directly from `describe` [is meaningless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716330/purpose-of-returning-by-const-value) (or not very helpful to say the least).

### Attemted solutions

So basically what I've thought of so far is:

- **overload `exporter.export<T>(...)` for `metadata`**, but that's not really a solution since it solves only the problem with the current class, while in the final product there will be many types of entities (And I'm not talking about . Overloading the function for *all* the types seems just wrong.
- **design an `immutable` wrapper** and return it from `describe`. That's what I'm currently doing, since I can't figure out a better way to solve the problem. The wrapper offers an implicit conversion to `const &T` and stores a `T` inside of itself, thus it can be passed directly to the `export` function.

### Question

Is there a better way to return an immutable POD class from a function? Am I missing something? For simplicity reasons lets assume `metadata` is defined as follows:

```
struct metadata{
    int parameter1;
    time_t parameter2;
};
```

and `describe` works as follows (currently, skipping the current solution):

```
metadata describe(const entity& obj){
   metadata m;
   m.parameter1 = obj.param1();
   m.parameter2 = obj.param2();
   return m;
}
```

Comment: The function shouldn't care if its return data is mutable or not, as it's by value and has no link to the function after it's executed. If caller wants to store it in a const variable, it is more than welcome to.

Comment: @NeilKirk since we're talking about __metadata__ (so data describing other data), it would be peculiar if the user could modify it and then pass it to the `exporter`, since he would just export false information to the database. The only way the metadata could change is when the data it describes changes, and that's not really for the user to monitor.

Comment: Is this for security or preventing accidental changes? Why not make the members of metadata private and provide only const getters.

Comment: @NeilKirk That would not be a POD anymore. Actually, the requirement to have a POD limits the solutions space quite heavily...

Comment: @DanielFrey True. I wonder where the requirement for a POD comes from. Is exporter doing something dodgy? Well you can have a non-POD version for the user to get, which is converted to a POD version inside exporter.

Comment: @PawełStawarz, your comment about user modifying metadata before passing it to `exporter::export` indicates that metadata needs to be an opaque pointer that a user cannot muck with. Otherwise, there are legal ways to construct a different metadata object before passing it to `exporter::export`.

Comment: @RSahu if the user decides to screw himself, that's not really something we care about. However - blessed with the knowledge from various other projects - we tend to acknowledge the average user doesn't read the documentation and tends to make unintentional mistakes. The more we can protect him from that possibility, the better, since instead of answering not-so-bright questions multiple times, we can focus on more important things. With a given monthly budget - less helpers hired == more programmers hired.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make the member variables `const`, you just need to initialize the object with an initializer list:

```
struct metadata{
    const int parameter1;
    const time_t parameter2;
};
```

and

```
metadata describe(const entity& obj){
   return { obj.param1(), obj.param2() };
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is some case the metadata isn't immutable. I find it's better to have a const object with non-const members, than the other way round.

Comment: I agree with the comment, it would be best if it was the other way round. Still - I'm upvoting this answer since it's far better than returning a wrapped instance, and - probably - it's the best solution there is. Gonna wait a bit more before accepting tho.

Comment: @PawełStawarz Given that it has to be a POD, you can't do much about it. You could of course return `const metadata` in addition to making the members `const` (just to document your intent that the user should *really* not change it), but since it's a POD the user can always create one with `metadata m{ 42, 1764 }` and use that instead. You can prevent accidents, but you can't protect yourself against malicious users.

Comment: Returning const metadata won't help as it can just be returned to a non-const variable directly.

Comment: +1 `You can prevent accidents, but you can't protect yourself against malicious users`

Comment: @Jarod42 GCC 4.8.1 says it's a POD.

Comment: @Jarod42 Strange. Clang [accepts it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99c9d6fed0a8b106) and §3.9/9 and §9 allow cv-qualified members IIUC. Do you have any standard reference which would make a struct non-POD because of a `const` member?

Comment: I trusted my version of gcc. so it should be a bug. (or maybe one version of the definition of pod disallows it and an other allows it...)

Comment: @PawełStawarz: GCC 4.9.0 says it's not http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9aa41bfd2e7a985.  Standard seems to imply it should be POD thought

Comment: @MooingDuck that's peculiar. We wanted to switch to 4.9.0 after this project, but now I'm not sure if that's a good idea. Clearly there's no reason for a struct with `const` members __not__ being a POD (both in terms of logic _and_ the Standard).

Comment: @MooingDuck: I think it must be a GCC bug. `std::is_pod<const int>::value` is true. And a struct composed of POD should also be POD. But GCC says it isn't. The struct with const int also fails `is_trivial` on GCC.

Comment: @ZanLynx: The only thing I can think of is that such a struct would have no implicit copy/move assignment, it's the only thing I can think of that would have any relevance at all.